# php extension compatability with php 5.6.6 or higher

Tags: php, mongodb, perl, ubuntu-14.04, pecl

Is any one installed the following library or extension `(curl,libcurl,pearl,pecl,mongodb driver for php)`  with `php 5.6.6` or higher not 7 in Ubuntu 14

I have used all of this with `php 5.5` now I afraid of version compatibility, 
**if any one ensure me** to can I migrate from  `Ubuntu  12.0.4` to 14 and `php 5.5` to `5.6.6` or higher ?

Answer (score 1):

The library or extension are third party softwares which they are developed by there own and able to bind in PHP or any other language.

E.g. [CURL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) library is developed in C and it can be used or bind in many different languages.

Also it is good to stay always up-to date, while upgrading to new version E.g PHP, you can check the [change-log](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php) of version and base on that you can understand, Is any library supporting change or not.

Many Web Servers are always try to upgrade or staying latest versions of languages or you can also inform them to upgrade server base on requirement and they will do, so it is no worry about server configuration.

From my system I upgraded from Ubuntu 12.4 to 14.4 and currently PHP version is 5.5.9 and every library is working fine.

And thing is that when the language version upgraded some good stuff also come, some bugs are fixed. So its cool stuff to always stay up